# Entity relationship validation in 3-tier architecture

Tags: .net, validation, architecture, orm, domain-driven-design

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC C# application with the MVC application as the UI layer in a 3-tire application and EF CodeFirst 5 as DAL.

```
DAL -> DTL
DTL <- BLL -> DAL
DTL <- UI -> BLL
```

*The arrows mean uses. (So DAL uses DTL and so on...)*

I've used POCO's as data transfer objects with data related validations in line with EF Code First.
My POCO's have relationships, and the POCO's in a relationship have relationships. Pretty standard...

All the classes in the BL handle a single POCO type, according to single responsibility rule.
The thing that puzzles me is how do I apply business rules and validation on the POCO's when they have relationships that are other BL's concern (to maintain the single responsibility)?

I'll try to give a simplified example: *(Read this more as a pseudo-code)*

```cs
public class Customer{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Enumerable<Person> Users { get; set; }
}

public class Person{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Customer BelongsTo { get; set; }
    public virtual Enumerable<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class Property{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class CustomerBL{

    private DALContext = new DALContext();        

    public void Add(Customer customer){
        DALContext.Customers.Add(customer);
        DALContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class PersonBL{

    private DALContext = new DALContext();        

    public void Add(Person person){
        if(person.Properties.Count() < 3)
             throw new ApplicationException("Each person must have at least three properties");

        DALContext.People.Add(person);
        DALContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

So my question is how do I, when adding a new customer, make sure that all users (if any are set on the customer object) are validated as as stated in the Add method of PersonBL without breaking the single responsibility rule (or at least break it in a good way) ?

***Keep in mind that Person can have other relationships which have other relationships and all have a specific BL with business rule. I've provided a "specific" example but I'm looking for a more general solution. Thank you!***

Answer (score 2):

You may need to have a look at your aggregate root design.

Remember that an AR should always be in a consistent state.  If you find that you need to validate something that shouldn't be validated then your aggregate root extends too far.  This may happen when you think about your object model in terms of navigation: from A I want to get to B and then to C.  This is where one trips up quite easily.  If you do not use your domain model for querying you do not need the navigation.  Lazy loading is another symptom of using your domain model for querying/navigation.

In your example `Customer` has a list of `Person` entities called `Users`.  A `Person` appears to be another AR.  An AR should not contain instances of other ARs as this makes your life a misery.  Break that bond.

So a `Customer` may have a list of `Users` (or whatever makes sense in your domain).  A user may have this structure:

```
public class User{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
}
```

As simple as that.  Now you need not worry about `Person` any longer as that is maintened elsewhere.  Therefore, try to represent other aggregate roots as value objects in the AR in question.

Answer (score 1):

**How about creating a separate validator class that does the validation?** Then, whenever you need to do validation for a particular entity, you can pass off that work to the validator, which will then return the broken rules.  This would allow you to reuse the validator in not only the Person repository, but also in other areas that may potentially add a parson as part of the unit of work.  This technique has been used in several business object frameworks that I've seen to keep validation independent of the rest of the main business logic and allows for easier testing as well.  [Here's a good post on the subject.](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/09/the-repository-pattern-part-2/)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm a little bit concerned with circular validation that this solution may imply. 

Eg. if Customer repository would validate Customer via Customer validator then Customer validator must validate Users (Person) via Person validator, which in turn must validate BelongsTo property via Customer validator and the circle goes round and round, dead lock. How can I avoid that?

Comment: What are you trying to validate there?  The validator is for each entity individually, but you wouldn't necessarily have it recursively trigger validation.  Since you're using EF CodeFirst, you can also create your own System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CustomValidationAttribute and annotate your properties with the validation in order to keeps things independent.  I didn't notice you were using Codefirst at first, but this the better (preferred) approach to property validation.  Have you read up on DataAnnotations in EF Codefirst?

Comment: I'm using DataAnnotations for validating entities (not in the example), but I'm trying to validate / apply business rule which DataAnnotations "cannot" be used for. That is validations that has to do with the whole entity and it's relations rather than the entities every single property

Comment: Oh, then I think it's fine to put those in the repository.  Repositories don't necessarily have to be mapped 1:1 with the tables in the DAL.  If you have entity validation on the entities themselves, and then the actual DbContext checking foreign key relationships, then I feel like it's totally fine to put anything extra into the repository, or even something that encompasses/reuses multiple repositories using a UnitOfWork pattern. (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: I'm actually using that pattern. But that doesn't cover business rules, if I put business rule validations in the repositories, then isn't it in the wrong place? perhaps my original question is misleading, but that's why I've chosen not to put that information there, because I want to avoid it to be about the patterns and more about the validations of the business rules it's self and not breaking the S in SOLID in major ways :)

Comment: I mean, you can always add validation logic in the business/service layer on top of the repositories.

Answer (score 1):

It is very important to establish correct *directions* of the relationships.

A good method usually is to eliminate collection properties within the entity classes. In your  particular case these are `Customer.Users` and `Person.Properties`. Let's focus on `Customer.Users`. Creating a `Users` property we indicate that a list of users is essential for a `Customer` entity. But then we see a contradiction

> make sure that all users (*if any are set on the customer object*) are
>   validated

We see that customers can exist without a list of users. Now the question is can `User` exist without a `Customer`. Probably not (if yes, maybe it is a different type of a user). So flipping the direction of a relationship would create a `Customer` property for the `User` entity and would eliminate `Users` collection property for a `Customer` entity.

This would improve your POCO's design, since some might argue that collection properties are not suitable for POCO's, especially virtual members.

So, we can improve the design, but how are we supposed to validate the relationship itself? The answer is that we need a different entity to perform this task. This could be a `CustomerRegistrationJournal` for e.g. It could have a method `RegisterCustomer` with two overloads: one taking a `Customer` entity for cases when there is no associated users, other `Customer` and a list of related `User` accounts. This method would invoke validation for each entity and invoke DAL. In such way it will be controlling the transaction of creating two types of entities.

DAL in this case should be modelled to enforce a foreign key constraint on `User` column referencing a `Customer`. This way it will provide a weak relationship. And that means that loading `User` will not load `Customer`, there will be no cascading updates or deletes. `User` entity will have an `Id` to the `Customer`, same as `User` table. This `Id` is essential for a `User`, but `Customer` *is not a component* of the `User`. Of course, you can model it to have entire `Customer` as a property, but that would be unnecessary overhead IMHO (even with NHibernate lazy loading).

Different design strategy should be applied modelling `Person.Properties`. For some reason some attributes of a Person must be represented by a list of `Property` [value objects](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html). Value objects do not exist without the entity. Value objects are components of other entities and they must be loaded and updated together with the entity. This is a strong one to many relationship. This is where a full potential of ORM is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I see your point and agree with what you're saying, but doesn't this imply that I can't use the "full" potential of EF or any ORM with the same relationship pattern ? So basically what would be the point of having any relationship described in any entity?

Comment: I see your point, that's how I've always done it in the past. I'm trying to see if an ORM is of any use at all in major applications with "real"/3-tier architecture? Is it doable at all? (without "down grading the entities") I think that EF Code First with migrations is a great approach and it would be very nice to use all of it's features. But using them is a challenge when thinking of the business rule validations and correctness of the entities in a more complicated system (more complicated than I exemplify above).